# Why is data.SX going out of resources for my no-Joins query?

Tags: support, data-explorer, jquery

I'm trying to run the following query on data.SX.com:

```
select
    OwnerUserId as [User Link],
    sum(case when up > 0 and down = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as socratism
from (
  select
    OwnerUserId,
    max(case when score > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as up,
    max(case when score < 1 then 1 else 0 end) as down
  from Posts
  where PostTypeId = 1 -- a question
  group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), creationDate, 111), OwnerUserId
) question_days
group by question_days.OwnerUserId
order by socratism desc;
```

This query involves no joining, so the table is not even that large. So what's the problem? What can I do to make the query more palatable?

Comment: the [User Link] is probably killing it

Comment: Because of the `[User Link]`, which crash when there are too many records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic column `[User Link]` is extremely expensive or at least that is what SQL Server thinks so it often gives up.

I've made a small [change](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/635033) by replacing the [magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) with the autolinking feature and this does work:

```sql
select
      'site://users/' 
    + cast(OwnerUserId as nvarchar) 
    + '|'
    + (select displayname from users du where du.id = owneruserid)  as [User],
    sum(case when up > 0 and down = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as socratism
from (
  select
    OwnerUserId,
    max(case when score > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as up,
    max(case when score < 1 then 1 else 0 end) as down
  from Posts
  where PostTypeId = 1 -- a question
  group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), creationDate, 111), OwnerUserId
) question_days
group by question_days.OwnerUserId
order by socratism desc;
```

The `site://` construct expands to the base URL of the site, in this case `http://stackoverflow.com` the rest is straight forward SQL string concatenation and inline SQL statements

```
    'site://users/'  --  'https://stackoverflow.com/users/' (1)
    + cast(OwnerUserId as nvarchar) -- '578411'
    + '|' -- the pipe symbol '|'
    + (select displayname  -- project the display name
       from users du       -- found in the users table, aliased as du     
       where du.id = owneruserid) -- the row where its id equals the owneruserid
```

end result:

`'https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411|rene'` and that string is rendered as a proper link, [rene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411), not as plain text.

<sup>1. Technically the site:// isn't expanded server side but client side. For the understanding of how this works it is an implementation detail not relevant for this discussion</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284086/152859. ;-)

Comment: Hmm, yeah @ShadowWizard but that author didn't add how you can fix that in specific cases, which is what this question asks. ... yes? no?

Comment: Why does your URL start with 'site://users' ?

Comment: to get the correct base url for the site @einpoklum

Comment: @rene well, if one asks "why is this broken?" expected answer would be "because X, Y, and to fix it, do Z". :)

Comment: Ok, [solved](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/635047/top-most-socratic-users-and-their-socratism), thanks!

Comment: Potentially bright future here: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5891682#5891682