# How to include hyperlinks in SEDE CSV dumps?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Glorfindel pointed me to two very helpful SEDE queries; and I thought: OK, let's save as CSV and import into a spread sheet and work that later on.

But to my surprise, the CSV dump only contains two columns:

> Post Link,CreationDate
>   "28928266","2015-03-08 15:42:03"

So - is there a way to not only get links in the SEDE query result view - but in the CSV file it creates for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* (but rene will probably prove me wrong) the Post Link [magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) (and for that matter, the custom scheme `site://`) are not compatible with the CSV export, and you should construct the link yourself instead, e.g. with constructions like

```sql
'https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/' + CAST(q.Id AS VARCHAR) AS 'Link'
```

(for queries which return answers, replace `/q/` with `/a/`)

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/705929) is an updated version of the query.

Comment: That works. Except for the thing that I will have to adapt it to use stackoverflow, not meta.SE !

Comment: [Technically the site:// isn't expanded server side but client side.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291783/158100) which explains why it doesn't work for CSV results: there is no JavaScript postprocessing on the output.