# Magic Column [User Link] produces "Out of Resources" error on simple SEDE queries

Tags: discussion, support, bug, data-explorer, magic-columns

<sup>Question shrunk since [the issue is known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308802/magic-column-user-link-produces-out-of-resources-error-on-simple-sede-que#comment1006355_308802) and will be addressed in due time.  (View [complete question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/308802/2).)</sup>

---

**Error in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) when using [magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns)**:
   [image: error]

- [**Example #1:**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835920/example-1-time-to-first-answer-no-link-to-question?daysBack=7) Control query (no magic column).
- [**Example #2:**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835923/example-2-time-to-first-answer-link-to-q-using-post-link?daysBack=7) Example #1 + added automated *[magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns)* `[Post Link]`
  - queries `7` days back without error
  - change parameter to `10` or more to reproduce [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG4MS.png).
- [**Example #3:**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835924/example-3-time-to-first-answer-link-to-q-using-3rd-join-to-posts?daysBack=7) Example #1 + added custom column`[My Post Link]`
  - same functionality as '`[Post Link]`" using an additional join. (Runs properly.)

**Similar question:**
- *[Out-of-resources when trying to run a popular DataExplorer query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284040/out-of-resources-when-trying-to-run-a-popular-dataexplorer-query)*  <sub>(known issue <=2016)</sub>

**Workaround Links:**
- `'site://posts/' + cast(id AS nvarchar)+'|'+title as [Alt. Post Link]`
- `'site://users/' + cast(userid as nvarchar) as [Alt. User Link]`
  <sup>(Source: [@Rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284086/370758))</sup>

Comment: I don't understand why you say the workaround I offered doesn't apply while you still use that workaround to overcome the issue. Unless I miss something this question is a duplicate of that question where I wrote my answer. As for *hasn't been addressed* is correct but obviously no-one seems interested enough to submit a PR on the  GitHub repo to solve it. This needs a community member to fix, not SE staff.

Comment: @rene funny - looking at your post again I realize I saw your workaround, dismissed it, wrote my post, and then came up with the *same* workaround on my own...anyhow I rephrased & no offence was intended, it was meant to give you credit for being the only other user who's attempted to address this.  ...I didn't realize there was a PR process on GitHub.  Is it specific to SEDE?  And why can't staff be involved?

Comment: SEDE is open source. It is only hosted (and seeded with data) by SE. Although staff are free to offer code (and some have done) the development of SEDE and fixing bugs is not on their priority list, at all. Although if you submit an PR you have to be ready to have it code-reviewed by Nick...

Comment: Very cool; I had no idea.  I assumed it was a 3rd party "plugin" for the site.

Comment: @rene Yeah, that's my bad (as usual). I have a fix for this somewhere, I just needed to test it...will do so and then put a PR out

Comment: @TimStone not trying to make you feel bad. I'm happy to help / assist if/when you see fit. Just ping me ...